# Drupal 7, passing URL arguments page not found

Tags: uri

Good evening. Please help me.

I built my website on my home pc using Wamp as webserver.  On one page I pass arguments to backend.php via URL.

Like this

```
echo "<a href='backend.php?g=$row[2]'><button >nbsp$row[1]</button></a>";
```

The code is working fine.

Now I uploaded the site to my godaddy hosting and can’t send the argument in the same manner.  I gives me 404.
The requested page "/backend.php?g=http://bc.luckyfaucets.com/" could not be found.

The code is exactly the same as on my home server,  .htaccess is the same and they both have clean URL enabled.
Can someone tell me the cause of this ?

This is the backend.php file.

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once
DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
variable_set('ref', $_GET['g']);
$g = $_GET['g'];

$con=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pwd,$database);

// Get infos siteid sitecyle from _sites_
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `siteid`, `sitecycle` FROM `_sites_` WHERE     `siteurl` = '$g'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
$siteid = $row[0];
$sitecycle = $row[1];
// Count time + sitecycle
$next = (time() + ($row[1]*60)+15);
}
// Update _counters_
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `siteid`, `uid` FROM _counters_ WHERE `uid` ='$user->uid' AND `siteid` ='$siteid'");
if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE _counters_ SET `cycleend` = '$next' WHERE `uid` = '$user->uid' AND `siteid` = '$siteid'");
    }
else
{
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO _counters_ (uid, siteid, cycleend) VALUES ('$user->uid', '$siteid', '$next')");
 }
 drupal_goto('page');
?>
```

I would like to know what/why the same code does work with Wamp but not on my hosting. Is this maybe cause by some setting at godaddy?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try an absolute URL in your href like: href='example.com/backend.php?g=$row[2]' and report the results.

Comment: Can you access the backend.php without arguments from your browser?

Comment: @tvl Thanks for the reply.

Yep, I can directly access the php file at http://example.com/backend.php 


I also tried theses variations .
`<a href=’example.com/backend.php?g=$row[2]'>`
`<a href='www.example.com/backend.php?g=$row[2]'>`
`<a href='http://www.example.com/backend.php?g=$row[2]'>`
Still getting 404 in all cases.

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_query` directly if you can avoid it. It seems your code can be subject to SQL injections now. Use Drupal's database API. `db_insert`, `db_update` etc will not allow you to make mistakes like that.

Comment: Just to get it right, when you type `example.com/backend.php` in your browser what happens?

Comment: @Molot
Thanks for the hint. For sure I want to use the best practices so I’m looking into the database API right, but do you think this can be related to my ‘page not found’ issue ?

Comment: @Wtower
When I go directly to backend.php I do get the page with errors due to empty arguments.

‘Notice: Undefined index: g in main()‘
‘Notice: Undefined index: g in main()‘
‘Undefined variable: siteid in main()’

Comment: @Matthr0X If I'm right, then someone with bad intentions and 5 minutes can make all your pages to be 404 ;) If you have time and backups, give me your URL and we'll see ;) Without URL it would be hard to investigate original issue, but don't give it here unless you are OK with loosing all your data.

Comment: You should also encode and decode the parameter. See `drupal_encode_path()` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_encode_path/7

Comment: @Molot I backed up my db. Please have a look.
http://luckyfaucets.com/index.php

Comment: @Wtower
I modified the code to this

`$path = '/backend.php?g='.$row[2];`
`drupal_encode_path($path);`
`echo "<a href='$path'><button ></button></a>";`

But the results are still the same…

Comment: Playing around adding different arguments to `http://www.luckyfaucets.com/backend.php?g=` I noticed something. 

I only get 404 when the g argument contains ‘http’ within.

i.e. 
`/backend.php?g=http://anything` give 404 
but not 
`/backend.php?g=anything`


Hoping this can help you help me

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your .htaccess file and uncomment the following line:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Hi, 
That was suggested on the drupal site so I did uncomment
RewriteBase /

But I’m still out of luck, having the same issue.